# How to convert hexadecimal value of OBD(On-Board Diagnostic) to a readable value

Tags: pi-3b+

Hello guys im having a problem about the conversion of hexadecimal of obd2 of a car to readable value like vehicle speed which is in 'km/h'

here's the code that i use

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyAMA0', 38400, timeout=1)

ser.write(b"01 0D \r")

speed_hex = ser.readline().split()

speed = float(int('0x'+speed_hex[3], 0 ))

print ('Speed: ', speed, 'km/h')
```

[image]

Comment: you forgot to tell us what values you are trying to convert

Comment: `ser.write(b"01 0D \r")`, are you sure for this line ? because you use byte and you pass hex value as string (not decimal or octal). maybe try `ser.write(b"\x01\x0D\r")` ?

Comment: Also, maybe check if the `baudrate` is correct for this device the datas can be missing if it is not the case.

Comment: `int('0x'+speed_hex[3], 0)`, you specify `base 0` for the conversion into hexadecimal , try real hexadecimal base : `base 16` let ``int('0x'+speed_hex[3], 16)`. for example:   float(int('0x'+'0c',16)) = 12.0

Comment: just print out the received value before trying to convert it, so we see what you receive and we might have ideas what went wrong during conversion.
So just add `print("Speed hex = %r" % speed_hex)` and post the output here.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.